# NSLocalizedString comment parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

As far as I understand from reading about NSLocalizedString on the Apple Developer site: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocalizedstring

The comment parameter in the NSLocalizedString initializer should perform the following action as described in the Apple dev docs "The comment to place above the key-value pair in the strings file."

So I assume that with the following code:

```
label.text = NSLocalizedString("HELLO_WORLD", comment: "Text for greeting label.")
```

Would update the corresponding string in my Localizable.strings file but all the file doesn't change and all that's in there is:

"HELLO_WORLD" = "Hello, World!";

Not sure if I'm going down the right road or not or if I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the comment argument.